# Kendo MVC Grid DataSourceResult to list of objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid in MVC which is filled with data from `T1ViewModel` (joined from `T1` in *`DB1`* and `T2` in *`DB2`*, where `T1` and `T2` are tables, *`DB1`* and *`DB2`* are databases).

`T1` has a `ShopID` column, and the `ShopName` column exists in `T2` of *`DB2`*.

I am using Entity Framework with two contexts. I'm loading data from `T1` into memory and then joining with `T2`, as I am only showing 10 records per page, and `T1` and `T2` have millions of records. This join happens on every page change which is hitting the performance.

Then I use `DataSourceRequest` to filter the records from `T1`.

```
public ActionResult T1_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    using(var context = new DB1Context())
    {
        // Get requested records from T1 into T1ViewModel which has shop name property
        DataSourceResult result = context.T1.select(r => new T1ViewModel{ShopId = r.ShopID.....}).ToDataSourceResult(request)
    }
    
    IEnumerable<T1ViewModel> T1RecordsFiltered = result.data;
    var ShopIds = T1RecordsFiltered.Select(T => T.ShopID);
    
    using(var context = new DB2Context())
    {
        // Get the T2 records that has matching ShopId in the list(ShopIds)
        var T2RecordsFiltered = context.T2.Where(T => ShopIds.Contains(T.ShopID)).ToList();
    }
    
    var t1ViewModel = 
        from t1rf in T1RecordsFiltered
        join t2rf in T2RecordsFiltered on t1rf.ShopID equals t2rf.ShopID into t2rfGroup
        from t2rfg in t2rfGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { t1rf, t2rfg };
                  
    var t1ViewModelDetails = t1ViewModel.Select(t =>
    {
        t.t1rf.ShopName = t.t2rfg.ShopName;
        return t.t1rf;
    });
    
    result.data = t1ViewModelDetails;
    
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
}
```

Now the problem is that my grid is groupable as well. But when I use that feature, `result.data` has list of `AggregateFunctionsGroup`. So I am not able to convert `result.data` into list of `T1ViewModel`.

Is this right way to do this? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. Rather than depending on the data of `dataSourceResult` I used `ToDataSourceResult` overloaded method to create the list of `t1ViewModels` and modified the `tViewModels` to update the `shopName` as shown below.

```
public ActionResult T1_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    List<T1ViewModel> t1ViewModels = new List<T1ViewModel>();
    DataSourceResult result;
    
    using (var context = new DB1Context())
    {
        // Get requested records from T1 into T1ViewModel which has shop name property
        result = context.T1.ToDataSourceResult(request, t =>
        {
            T1ViewModel tvm = T1ViewModel.FromModel(t);
            t1ViewModels.Add(tvm);
            return tvm;
        });
    }
    
    var ShopIds = t1ViewModels.Select(T => T.ShopID);

    using (var context = new DB2Context())
    {
        // Get the T2 records that has matching ShopId in the list(ShopIds)
        var T2RecordsFiltered = context.T2
            .Where(T => ShopIds.Contains(T.ShopID))
            .ToList();
    }
    
    var t1ViewModelDetails = 
        from t1vm in t1ViewModels
        join t2rf in T2RecordsFiltered on t1vm.ShopID equals t2rf.ShopID into t2rfGroup
        from t2rfg in t2rfGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { t1vm, t2rfg };

    t1ViewModelDetails.Select(t =>
    {
        t.t1vm.ShopName = t.t2rfg.ShopName;
        return t.t1vm;
    });

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```